# JMeter with jp@gc Firefox WebDriver: Different browser size in remote execution

Tags: selenium, firefox, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am using JMeter with the [jp@gc WebDriver](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FirefoxDriverConfig/) set (v1.3.1) and the Firefox-driver (Firefox version: 31.0).
My testplan runs through just fine when I execute it directly from JMeter.
I can see browsers opening up and can follow the test execution.

When I run it via the JMeter-Server though by remote execution the test fails reproducibly in one sampler with the following error message:

> ERROR - com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.WebDriverSampler: Timed out after 300 seconds waiting for element to be clickable: By.id: Wizard

I have configured the sampler to take a screenshot on error but this looks fine. The sampler does wait for the element to be clickable before actually trying to click it.

The weird thing is - as mentioned above - that this doesn't happen when I directly execute the test (i.e. from JMeter GUI)

One difference I noticed for the remote execution is, that the browser doesn't actually open (as in "visibly") on the target machine. I can see though that the process is running with "-foreground" option.
This is probably fine, but for debugging purposes I'd like to see what is actually going on. This could help in determining what is different in this scenario.

Any ideas on how I can manage to have the browser open up in that case as well?
Or alternativly, any ideas on how local and remote execution differ?

Edit: I think I tracked this down to the browser size being different in direct vs. remote execution. This became apparent after I switched from the Firefox driver to the Chrome driver. The test still failed in remote execution, but the Screenshot showed both horizontal & vertical scrollbars. Firefox did not, but the screenshot apparently doesn't show the "full truth".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is indeed caused by different browser size when comparing direct and remote execution. The element that I wanted to click in my test was simply out of screen in remote execution and therefore couldn't be clicked. It can however be found and also matches the "elementToBeClickable" condition which is a bit counter-intuitive.

In order to avoid this I specifically set a "safe" and fixed browser size when the test starts:

```
WDS.browser.manage().window().setPosition(new pkg.Point(0, 0))
WDS.browser.manage().window().setSize(new pkg.Dimension(1280, 1024))
```

With this direct & remote execution have identical sizes and the test runs as expected.
Note that

```
WDS.browser.manage().window().maximize()
```

does not work in remote execution!
This seems to somehow reduce the screensize, even if it was previously set to a "safe" size.